# vue js - conditional styling is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a heart symbol attached with a submit button that upon clicking it, the color should changed.

My code:

```
 <template>
    
     <button v-bind:class="classes" type="submit" @click="toggle">
            <span v-text="this.count"></span>
            <i class="fas fa-heart fa-sm" v-bind:style="styleObject"></i>
    </button>
        
    </template>
    
    
    <script>
    export default {
        props: ['reply'],
    
        data(){
            return {
                isFavorited: this.reply.isFavorited,
                count: this.reply.favorites_count
            }
        },
    
        computed: {
            classes(){
                return ['btn',this.isFavorited ? 'btn-primary':'btn-secondary'];
            },
            styleObject(){
                return this.isFavorited ? 'color:red':'color:white';
            } 
        },
    .......
methods: {
        toggle(){
            // check if reply is favorited
            if(this.isFavorited){
                axios.delete('/replies/'+this.reply.id+'/favorites');
                this.isFavorited = false;
                this.count--;
            }else{
                 axios.post('/replies/'+this.reply.id+'/favorites');
                this.isFavorited = true;
                this.count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

So I bind the icon to styleObject and upon clicking the button, the color is not changing unless  I refresh the page.The class button however is working as expected.

I also tried writing it like this using inline style binding:

```
 <span class="fas fa-heart fa-sm" v-bind:style="[this.isFavorited ? {'color' : 'red'} : {'color' : 'white'}]"></span>
```

and also this way:

```
 styleObject(){
             return { color: this.isFavorited ? 'red' : 'white' };
        }
```

I tried inspect it using vue dev tool and it does show the color has changed upon clicking but it's not reflecting on my screen.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `styleObject` should return an object, because in Vue the binding `style` attribute is in an object or array syntax.

```js
styleObject() {
  return this.isFavorited ? { color: 'red' } : { color: 'white' };
}
```

Better solution by @Terry:

```
styleObject() {
  return { color: this.isFavorited ? 'red' : 'white' };
}
```

Comment: Even better: `return { color: this.isFavorited ? 'red' : 'white' };`

Comment: I will add that to the post :)

Comment: @FloWy Is that why my button classes() is working?

Comment: Yes, that is the array syntax.

Comment: You can find more information in the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Comment: @FloWy Just tested your solution and Terry's solution, it still doesn't change and not working.

Comment: @Terry your solution is not workin either.

Comment: For me, both versions are working. Maybe there is some issue with manipulating `isFavorited`?

Comment: @FloWy Hmm, cause refreshing the page will reflect the color changes. If there is an issue manipulatin ```isFavorited```, then why does my button classes work?

Comment: I did a little bit of checking through my vue inspecting tools and upon clicking the button, the state color does change red to white and vice versa but does not reflect on my view.

Comment: Maybe [that fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FloWy/91tduv7a/1/) will help you.

Comment: @FloWy My code already included that, you can check my edited post.

Comment: Updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FloWy/39owqvmt/2/). Maybe there is some caching error in the dev server. Did you try to restart it?

Comment: I think if you can simulate the fiddle with an icon from font-awesome to see if it would work rather than the word test itself.

Comment: Works for [me](https://jsfiddle.net/FloWy/39owqvmt/3/)

Comment: I tested this https://jsfiddle.net/fgeky25p/1/ and it works

Comment: I tried disabling the cache, using icognito window, etc but no luck